# replace 'replacement character' for a database

Tags: sed

Due to some encoding problems, some characters in my database have been interpreted uncorrectly. Some chars have been replaced with the '[replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replacement_character#Replacement_character)'.
I need to find all such chars and replace them with space. I have been googling different solutions using sed, bash, perl, etc with no luck. Could someone share a solution how to find such characters (i.e. looking for this character in hex/octal [value](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm)) and replace them with any other character?

Thanks.

Comment: bash is so the wrong tool for this.

Comment: Might just possibly be useful if you mentioned some tiny details like what database you're using...

Comment: Is your _database_ a file? Can you give an example how you see such _replacement characters_?

Comment: The Unicode "Replacement Character" glyph  is usually not what is in the underlying data storage system: It's normally subbed in at the display layer (because of a decoding failure), and doesn't actually tell you what the underlying code was/is.  You need to know *that* (and what DB you're talking about) in order to go about cleaning things up...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Unicode "Replacement Character" glyph is usually not what is in the underlying data storage system: It's normally subbed in at the display layer (because of a decoding failure), and doesn't actually tell you what the underlying code was/is.

You have two options here:

The first (and best) is to find out what the underlying glyph/code is and use your database tools in order to cleanin things up.

The second is to export your data through something that does the Unicode conversions, search/replace the "Replacement Character" code there, and re-import your data.  This is generally infeasible for all but the smallest data sets (and if the problem is that your ***workstation*** can't figure out what to do with the Unicode glyphs it won't fix your problem).

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer. You are right, I have dumped my database and found number of different strange characters in my dump. The database seems to have been affected by malicious code. I would not figure out this without your help.